# How to calculate the adjoint operator for a given operator?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, adjoint-operators

While I was learning about operators I stumbled apon the following defintion.

Definition:

Let $T : H_1 \rightarrow H_2$ be a linear map.
There exists an operator $T^* H_2 \rightarrow H_1$ such that
$\langle Tx,y \rangle_{H_2}=\langle x,T^*y \rangle_{H_1}$ (1)

The operator $T^*$ is called the adjoint operator (regarding $T$).

I wanted to try some (simple looking exercise) to get a feeling for this topic.

Exercise:
The two-sided right shift operator $T: l^2(\mathbb{Z}) \rightarrow l^2(\mathbb{Z})$
, where $l^2(\mathbb{Z}):=${$(...,x_{-n},x_{-n+1},...,x_{-1},x_0,x_1,...,x_{n},...) \text{sucht that} x_k \in \mathbb{K} \text{and} \sum_{\infty}^{\infty}|x_k|^2 < \infty $}.

The operator $T$ is defined as $ T(x_n)_n = (x_{n-1})_n $.

Determine $T^*$, and find out if $T$ is a unitary operator (i.e. $T^*T=TT^*$)

My approach:
First, I wanted to understand how $T$ "acts".

So let $(x_n)_{n \in \mathbb{Z}}$ be in $l^2(\mathbb{Z})$, $(x_n)_{n \in \mathbb{Z}}=(...,x_{-n},...,x_{-1},x_0,x_1,...,x_n,...)$

than $T(x_n)_{n \in \mathbb{Z}}=(x_{n-1})_{n \in \mathbb{Z}}=(...,x_{-n-1},...,x_{-2},x_{-1},x_0,...,x_{n-1},...)$
just shifts the sequence to the right (okay, I see where the name for this operator comes from)

I am not really sure how to use (1) to determine $ T^* $, by guessing I would say that $T^*(x_n)_{n \in \mathbb{Z}}=(x_{n+1})_{n \in \mathbb{Z}}$.

Then it would be easy to see that $T^*T=id$ and $TT^*=id$ and thus $T$ is unitary.

Question: Is my answer correct? And although it was possible to solve this by guessing, I would like to know how to solve it by using the definition of adjoint operator. Would be thankful if someone could show me.

Comment: The definition you report is a theorem but you forgot a hypothesis: the linear map $T$ must be continuous, i.e. satisfy$$\forall x\in H_1\quad\|T(x)\|\le C\|x\|$$for some constant $C.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $x\in l^2(\mathbb{Z})$ and $T:l^2(\mathbb{Z})\rightarrow l^2(\mathbb{Z})$ be defined as $T(x_n) = (x_{n-1})$. Then for any $y\in l^2(\mathbb{Z})$ we have
\begin{align}
\langle Tx, y\rangle = \sum_{j=-\infty}^\infty (Tx_n)_jy_j = \sum_{j=-\infty}^\infty x_{j-1} y_j = \sum_{j=-\infty}^\infty x_{j} y_{j+1},
\end{align}
using an index shift in the last equation. Can you proceed from here?

Comment: would it continue like =$\sum_{j=- \infty}^{\infty}x_j(T^*y_n)_{j+1}=\sum_{j=- \infty}^{\infty}x_j(T^*y_{n+1})_{j}=\langle x,T^*y \rangle $ where $T^*(y_n)_n=(y_{n+1})_n$

Comment: In your second equality it should be $(T^\ast y_n)_j$. And to be precise, you would need to argue why $\langle Tx,y\rangle = \langle x,Sy\rangle$ with $S(x_n) = (x_{n+1})$ implies that actually we have $S = T^\ast$, and that this operator is bounded.

Comment: Doesn't it follow from $\langle Tx,y \rangle = \langle x,Sy \rangle $ , that $S=T^*$? Isn't this just the definition of adjoint operator?

Comment: Yes it follows from that equality, but only because the adjoint operator $T^\ast$ is unique.

Answer (score 2):

Observe that $$\langle T^*Tx,x\rangle =\|Tx\|^2=\|x\|^2=\langle x,x\rangle $$ Hence $T^*T=I.$ Moreover $T$ is invertible and $T^{-1}(x_n)=(x_{n+1}).$ Thus $T^*=T^{-1}$ therefore $T$ is a unitary operator.

Summarizing an invertible isometry is always a unitary operator.